# Using Photoshop - how do I make text "wrap" (break) around an image like in the images linked in this post?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

Example 1:

[image: Example 1]

Example 2:

[image: Example 2]

Is there a simple and semi-automatic way to do this? I know I can do it manually, but there ought to be some way to make the text automatically break when it reaches some sort of defined "edge".

PS. For anyone wondering: The text is in Swedish. ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure where "simple" and "semi-automatic" start, but there is a simple way to make shaped area text without having to indent lines by hand.

Create a path in the shape you need using the Pen tool. When you hover over it with the text tool, you'll see the cursor change to the Area Text tool (little parentheses around the I-bar). You can use a shape layer, too, but there's no need.

Type the text, and it will flow inside the path. If you need to change the shape later, just edit the path.

**For more you can see these detailed tutorial :**

1. [Wrapping Text Around An Object](http://pshero.com/photoshop-tutorials/graphic-design/wrapping-text-around-an-object)
2. [Photoshop Text Wrap - Faking Text Wrap In Photoshop](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photoshop-text/text-effects/text-wrap/)

Comment: Is this the same thing as to what Pankaj is referring to? Because in that case that is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Yes. Variations on the same theme. The basic technique is to set up a path that's the shape you need, then put the text in it. The pen tool is what I would use, simply because it's the most flexible, but anything that ends up with a path will work.

Comment: Yes we both are on the same track, just to make it more clear and approachable I am adding resources to this answer in case anyone else need that, Silly me i could have done this changes before rather than posting a new answer, Alan I hope you wont mind

Comment: Hi Pankaj -- I don't mind in the least. That's an elegant solution that puts everything in one answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple? Semi-automatic?  No.

With Photoshop you must manually create soft returns or indents where needed. **Photoshop** simply is not designed to be a text or layout editor. And, for this reason, Photoshop has no inherent text-wrap capabilities. Photoshop can  *constrain* text to a shape which is **not** the same as text wraps ([See explanation here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6156/what-is-the-difference-between-wrapped-text-and-constrained-text)).

Using a layout app such as Adobe Indesign or QuarkXPress would easily allow you to create text wraps. This is how your examples are done - via layout software, not photo software.

Comment: Not correct; see Alan's answer.

Comment: That's your opinion. Constraining text to a shape is not the same as a text wrap. I urge you to try both... use the text area constrained in Photoshop, then create the same layout in Indesign using a text wrap. Drastically different results.

Comment: The problem bit is "With Photoshop you must manually create soft returns or indents where needed". Edit a bit and it's a good answer.

Comment: It's a good answer without an edit. You DO need to create indents and soft returns for a text wrap. Again.. constraining area text to a shape is different entirely. Try both. You'll see.

Comment: From a practical standpoint, although you are hair-splittingly correct, it's not *useful* to point out the difference (which the OP wouldn't understand anyway, and that's who we're trying to help), especially if you don't then make it clear exactly what distinction you are talking about. That's e100's point. A good answer is *for the questioner*, not just the question.

Comment: Having said all this - what is the drastic difference?  Scott, can you post a quick side-by-side to show what you're talking about (perhaps an example that really shows off the difference, not necessarily just constrained to the original question)?  I promise I'm interested in your answer, not furthering any kind of argument.  Your answer has value; I'd like to know what it is!

Comment: He's already answered my additional question [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6156/what-is-the-difference-between-wrapped-text-and-constrained-text).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is the old school way. Photoshop is not really designed to handle a lot of text so nest it in something that is.

Open a new document in Illustrator with two layers. On the bottom layer, place the image you want to wrap. If you have already built this as a PSD, place it. On the top layer, manually wrap your text box around the object. This allows you to avoid the dreaded Soft Return nightmare when you have to edit the copy.

Open the image in Photoshop. Drag in the Illustrator layers as a Vector Smart Object. Open the new Vector Smart Object, turn off the bottom layer and save it. This leaves the text only in PS.

The text is now in PS and you can use all the effects you want. Should you need to edit the text - not that we ever have to - just open the Vector Smart Layer.

If you change or update the image, it will be updated in AI so you can change your wrap. I turn off the Vector Smart Layers in PS when I update the AI Vector Layer.

From the design and production world, fast, easy and accurate equals less time and more money. Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but for this specific context I needed to do it all in Photoshop. Thanks for the answer, though! I'm sure it'll be useful for someone else.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible.
This Youtube Video explains quite well:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y32csVs8uVs