# Using Letters with counters / cutouts as work paths

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In following this tutorial on [Using Text as Container](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photoshop-text/text-effects/text-inside-text.php) which essentially explains how to create a path from a letter, I've run into difficultly when trying to follow this on any letter that has a counter... like a, b, d, etc.  When I right-click inside the original text, and convert it to a work path, and then I click inside the work path to begin typing with a new type tool... letters! *lose* their counters and the path is defined strictly by its outer edge.  See the screenshot:

[image: Where's the counter?]

How can I adjust the work path so that the counter is preserved and you can see the hole in the letter *a* like you'd expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Photoshop, you can not.

Photoshop only offers constrained text, not wrapped text. For the difference between the two, see this question: [What is the difference between "wrapped" text and "constrained" text?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6156/what-is-the-difference-between-wrapped-text-and-constrained-text/6167#6167)

Comment: Noooooo!  Appreciate the answer even though it isn't what I'd like to hear.  Is this something that I can do with vectors then?  Say in Inkscape?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Inkscape. I do know that wraps are possible in Indesign or Illustrator.