# How can I slant text like this in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

[image]

I don't have the money to buy Illustrator but I have Photoshop. How can align my text on a diagonal like this?

If I can't do it in Photoshop how can I do this for free?

Comment: Is it too much work to just make each of the individual paths?

Comment: To be clear... the example *isn't* how you want the text? You want to type on a diagonal path?

Answer (score 3):

It is merely **[constrained text](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6156/what-is-the-difference-between-wrapped-text-and-constrained-text)**. That is... a shape that Photoshop restricts text to.

- Grab the **Pen Tool** and draw a shape
- Grab the **Type Tool** and click the shape. 
  You'll see the I beam cursor get a circle around it `(I)`
- Type
- Delete the shape layer
- Adjust the text how you'd like

[image]

You can then further alter the constraining shape using the **Direct Selection Tool** or the **Pen Tool**.