# Placing text inside shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, font-design

This may be a silly question but...

Im pretty new to Illustrator and I have the number 12 and i need to type text inside each number without it going outside the lines of the numbers. How do I do this? Thanks

Comment: Not saying this is a duplicate, but I asked a similar question very recently. Link here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/using-photoshop-how-do-i-make-text-wrap-break-around-an-image-like-in-the If nothing else, it might help someone.

Answer (score 8):

If I understand your question correct, you want to write letters that are contained within a parent shape, such as a numerical character, the short answer is: use the **Type Area Tool**.

Here's how you do that:

**1.** Using the **Type Tool**, type your number character.

[image]

**2**. Choose **Type > Create Outlines** or press `Shift-Command-0/Shift-Ctrl-0`. (If you want your number shape to remain as a background object in the end, make a duplicate of it now since the shape will disappear in step 5.)

[image][image: Your text becomes non-editable (path outlines)]

**3**. Choose **Object > Compound Path > Release**. (Note: Type Area Tool won't work on compound or masking paths.)

[image]

**4.** Choose the **Type Area Tool** in the Tools Palette.

**5.** Click on the number shape and start typing. (Note: if you get a message complaining about non-compound, non-masking paths, try clicking on one of the anchor points.)

[image]

Comment: Thats really helpful. Thank you. What about if I want to have the black outline of the number around the text? If that makes sense?

Comment: Then I would duplicate the number and give it a stroke.

Comment: I know that this is late, but when I try this with an "o" or zero, either the whole shape fills in or just oval recess in the center, not the outer thin part of the character. How do I correct this? Thanks!!!!

Comment: to handle he inner portion of a "p", "o", "a", etc, simply select the inner shape with the `white` arrow (direct selection tool), and fill it with white, or whatever background color your working file has.

Answer (score -2):

you have to link the two paths (the inner and outer circles) to make it on continuous shape much like you would with stencil cut-outs.